# How did 徹 originally signify a hand breaking a pot?

Tags: glyph-origin

1. Is [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BE%B9#Glyph_origin), which can be wrong, correct?

> *[彳](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BD%B3#Chinese)* + *[育](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%82%B2#Chinese)* + *[攵](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%94%B5#Chinese)* (“hand”) – originally a hand breaking a pot.

2. If it is, 攵 = hand, correct?
3. But which **Glyph (Is this the correct term? Or is this Morph? Morpheme?)** represents "breaking"?
4. Which Glyph represents "a pot"?

I found no evidence for this in Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007).

[image]

[CUHK's  詳解](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BE%B9) mentions hands, but no breaking or pots.

> 甲骨文或從「丑」、「廾」，「丑」象手形，「廾」象兩手之形

Comment: CUHK does actually mention a cooking vessel ("pot", if you will). You'll need to put in a bit more investigative effort, like clicking on 「鬲」 in CUHK's 詳解, rather than throwing a paragraph of text at Google translate and hoping that you've got a correct translation and/or not missed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| 時期 字體 | 字形｜[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B8%E5%AE%9A) | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: ⿰鬲丑] | [前](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)6.35.1 [合集8073](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=8073&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: ⿰鬲又] | [史墻盤](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi_Qiang_pan) [集成10175](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=10175&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state)) 金 | [image: ⿰鬲攵] | 羌鐘 [集成161](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=161&jgwfl=) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image] | [攴部・古文](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=112) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
|  | **字形** |  |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 徹] | 日書乙種50 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
| [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 徹] | 縱橫家書51 [馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts) |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) 隸 | [image: 徹] | [儀禮](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette_and_Ceremonial)・[泰射](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%84%80%E7%A6%AE#-%7B%E5%87%BA%E5%9C%9F%E7%89%88%E6%9C%AC%7D-) [熹平石經](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiping_Stone_Classics) |
| 楷 | [image: 徹] |  |

「徹」 was originally 「⿰鬲丑」 or 「⿰鬲又」, depicting a *hand* [「丑」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=64) or [「又」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) with a *cooking vessel* [「鬲」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1959), indicating the meaning *to clear away cooking utensils* > *to remove*.

To further emphasise *action* and *movement*, 「又」 was later slightly changed to the verb component [「攵」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=31257), and 「彳」 (*motion*) was added. 「鬲」 was eventually corrupted into [「育」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=689), forming the modern 「徹」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%A7%81)
- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [異體字表](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants)